# How to split an image into multiple small images based on the blank area or edge detection Python OpenCV?

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

[image: The image is here]

I have a lot of images similar to it. The size of each text / roman number may be different since it's handwriting.

How do I save each text/roman number to `.png` format individually?
There are 9 texts with one dot. So the output should be 10 or 9 images respectively. The space between each text/ roman number is different. Should I crop them based on the canny edges or any better ways?

I am not sure how difficult it is, since I am a beginner in CV. But I am planning to do this for my project.

Comment: Apply morphology open to thicken and close small gaps. Then get contours and their bounding boxes and crop the bounding boxes.

Answer (score 6):

The main idea is to use [dilation](https://opencv24-python-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html#dilation) to combine individual contours together and then individually crop each. Here's a simple method

1. **Obtain binary image.** [Load the image](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-opencv-cv2-imread-method/),  [grayscale](https://opencv24-python-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/stable/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_colorspaces/py_colorspaces.html), [Gaussian blur](https://opencv24-python-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_filtering/py_filtering.html#gaussian-filtering), [Otsu's threshold](https://opencv24-python-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_thresholding/py_thresholding.html#otsus-binarization), then [dilate](https://opencv24-python-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html#dilation) to obtain a binary black/white image.
2. **Extract ROI.** [Find contours](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#findcontours), [obtain bounding boxes](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=boundingrect#boundingrect), extract ROI using Numpy slicing, and save each ROI

---

Detected ROIs highlighted in green

[image]

Extracted and saved ROIs

[image]

```
import cv2

# Load image, grayscale, Gaussian blur, Otsu's threshold, dilate
image = cv2.imread('1.jpg')
original = image.copy()
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5,5), 0)
thresh = cv2.threshold(blur, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (15,15))
dilate = cv2.dilate(thresh, kernel, iterations=2)

# Find contours, obtain bounding box coordinates, and extract ROI
cnts = cv2.findContours(dilate, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
image_number = 0
for c in cnts:
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (36,255,12), 3)
    ROI = original[y:y+h, x:x+w]
    cv2.imwrite("ROI_{}.png".format(image_number), ROI)
    image_number += 1

cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('dilate', dilate)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: Brilliant work! I'm shocked this isn't an accepted answer.